# how to stick the footer to the bottom of the page while moving it upward in a parallax-like effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I have a project where the requirement is to move the footer ( `#footer` ) upward while scrolling down the page in a parallax-like effect. When you start scrolling down the page, the footer should start moving upward only until it's visible in the (bottom part of the) viewport.

The footer should have covered most of the preceding `<div>` half way up and in full when it has reached the top of the viewport.

The page may have a similar html structure like this :

```
<body>
    <div id="sectionA" class="div">First section</div>
    <div id="sectionB" class="div">Second section</div>
    <div id="sectionC" class="div">Third section
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" class="div cf">Footer</div>
</body>
```

The parallax-like effect is achieved via javascript/jQuery adding a dynamic *negative* value to the `top` CSS property of the (relative positioned) footer. Here is the code for what it matters :

```
var $window = jQuery(window),
    $footer = jQuery("#footer"),
    $viewport = window.innerHeight,
    $startEffect = $footer.offset().top - $viewport;

function footerParallax() {
    var $scrollPos = $window.scrollTop() - $startEffect,
        $ratio = 0.6;
    $footer.css({
        top: -($scrollPos * $ratio)
    });
}

$window.scroll(function () {
    footerParallax();
});
```

The (obvious) issue is that as soon as the `top` property starts getting a *negative* value, the footer starts moving away from the bottom of the page.

I have prepared a **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cnRsr/)** and assigned colors to each section and `body` to make it clearer. The `body` (dark-red) is visible under the footer after scrolling to the bottom.

What have I tried?

- modifying the `margin-top` instead of the `top` property:  *this does the trick, however the preceding `<div>` that has to be covered by the footer (`#sectionC` in the example above) overlaps the contents of the footer and breaks its layout regardless that it is not visible due to its `z-index` property (added some floating boxes in the fiddle to make it evident.... a clearfix hack didn't help either.)*
- setting a `static` position to the footer: *neither `top` or `margin-top` have effect over a `static` element.*
- Changing/reducing dynamically the `height` of `#sectionC` instead of `top` of footer to produce the effect of moving the second upwards :  *the footer stops moving as soon as `height` is equal to `0` (neither negative size or negative paddings are allowed)*
- Changed the `height` dynamically of the `html` and/or `body` tags to no avail.

I have also tried some parallax plugins like [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr) and [skrollr-stylesheets](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr-stylesheets) and some others.

The problem with this solution (same with others) is that it relays in an specific (offset) position of the footer measured in px and set in a `data` attribute, but if the content changes dynamically, for example using the masonry plugin to arrange elements in another section of the document, the measures become inaccurate and the footer may start moving too early or too late.

By the way, other CSS sticky-footer techniques won't work because, well, they actually push the footer to the bottom of the page, and here we are doing the opposite.

I guess the question is either :

- how to keep the footer stick to the bottom of the page while it is moved upwards? - or -
- how to reduce the gap to `0` between the end of the document and the bottom edge of the footer?

I am starting to think that this issue has not a real solution the way it is, or maybe I am already too tired to see the obvious. I am interested in learning alternative solutions or hacks via CSS / javascript / jQuery or all of the above.

Bear in mind that I am not asking how to create the parallax effect UNLESS a totally different approach (or tweaks to the existing js code) solves the position issue.

**IMPORTANT** : Please consider that this is a WP site with an `XHTML 1.0 Transitional DOCTYPE`, and has installed many other jQuery plugins like masonry, scrollTo, jQuery UI, etc.  I may have not control to change many things from the original structure (and I don't want to) so the idea is to implement this without breaking too many things and from a modular script.

**EDIT #1** : Added a graphic to clarify the question.

- **Figure A**. shows a regular web page scrolled down to the end. The red square represents the viewport and the footer (grey) is slighted moved to the right for illustration purposes. The `body` has a reddish background color (not visible in normal conditions) just for illustration purposes too. **NOTE**: the `height` of each section as well as the `height` of the footer is determined by their content (forms, images, text, etc.) so is NOT fixed.
- **Figure B**. shows the current issue: If footer slides up in a parallax-like effect (see **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cnRsr/)** for reference) while scrolling down the page, it starts covering any preceding section above it (WITHOUT modifying neither its own `height` or the `height` of the preceding sections) AND it also starts separating itself from the bottom of the page, therefore the `body`'s color background becomes visible. **NOTE**: the bigger the viewport is (fullscreen mode for instance) the higher the footer is moved upward (and more content is covered by it)
- **Figure C**. is the expected result: the footer should be stuck to the bottom of the page, in other words, it should be the last visible element after the page has been totally scrolled down (and not the body background as in Figure B.) **Notice** that the contents and the size of each section (including the footer) should (ideally) remain untouched. Having said that, adding padding bottom to the footer or increasing its height is not the expected result since it would break its original visual layout.

[image]

Comment: So much text, and I still don't understand what you want. I have something to say though: skrollr does not require offsets in absolute values. You can for example use `data-bottom` which means "when the bottom of the element is at the bottom of the viewport"

Comment: @Prinzhorn : will check that with skrollr, thanks. PS. if you don't understand the text check the jsfiddle. What I want is not to have the body background visible (the red gap between the bottom edge of the footer and the bottom of the viewport) does it make sense?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. Maybe you find a page which already does what you're asking for.

Comment: @Prinzhorn : what I want is to animate the footer up while scrolling the page down (parallax-like) AND the last thing I want to see after finishing scrolling the page is the bottom of the footer itself (grey in jsfiddle) and not the `body` color background (in red) Honestly I don't think is that difficult to get. On the other hand, I have successfully implemented skrollr in other projects (despite is poorly documented) but with absolute positioned elements. Wonder if skrollr is the right tool for the job in this particular case and how.

Comment: My interpretation of the way your fiddle and section heights are setup implies a container of 500px in height - at least for the purposes of this question.  Is that accurate or have I misinterpreted?

Comment: @dc5 : sorry, the height of any section is not fixed, it could even dynamically change if using masonry plugin to filter elements. I just set a random 500px height to have an scrollable page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How was it solved?

As I mentioned in my question, I was too tired to see the obvious but @dc5's answer put me on the right track :

```
To help keep the footer's layout from being affected, 
wrapping the content of the footer in an absolutely 
positioned div does the trick
```

Based on that comment, the answer became simpler than the whole code he proposed needing only :

- (dynamically) wrapping the content of the footer in an absolutely positioned `div` using jQuery's `.wrapInner()` method
- animating the footer by setting the `margin-top` property instead of the `top` property

So this extra CSS :

```
#footerInnerWrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #666 /* same as footer */
}
```

and the tweaked original code

```
var $window = jQuery(window),
    $footer = jQuery("#footer"),
    $viewport = window.innerHeight,
    $startEffect = $footer.offset().top - $viewport;

// add inner wrapper
$footer.wrapInner('<div id="footerInnerWrapper" />');

function footerParallax() {
    var $scrollPos = $window.scrollTop() - $startEffect,
        $ratio = 0.6;
    $footer.css({
        // top: -($scrollPos * $ratio) 
        marginTop: -($scrollPos * $ratio)
    });
}

$window.scroll(function () {
    footerParallax();
});
```

did the trick. See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cnRsr/20/)**

Comment: Nice! I'm glad I was able to help.  I'd gotten stuck in the explicit math trying to work through a solution without margin-top and didn't think to go back and try your original, much simpler, algorithm.

Answer (score 6):

**Updated Version**

Below is an updated version that should better matches your requirements.

This version goes back to `relative` positioning for the footer element and uses `margin-top` to position it.

`margin-top` is calculated off of the previous elements offset, height and current window scroll position.  It then uses either

1. the viewport height if the footer starts offscreen
2. the initial top value of the footer element (`$startEffect`) if the footer started onscreen

to determine the actual value for margin-top.

To help keep the footer's layout from being affected by this, wrapping the content of the footer in an absolutely positioned div did the trick for the sample code provided.

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cnRsr/17/)

CSS:

```
#footer > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    ...
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="footer" class="div cf"><div>Footer</div></div>
```

Code:

```
var $window = jQuery(window),
    $footer = jQuery("#footer"),
    $viewport = window.innerHeight,
    $startEffect = $footer.offset().top;
    $prev = $footer.prev(),
    $useStartEffect = $startEffect < $viewport;


function footerParallax() {
    var $scrollPos = $window.scrollTop() - $startEffect,
        $ratio = 0.6;

    var prevOffset = $prev.offset().top + $prev.height() - $window.scrollTop();
    var marginTop = 0;

    if(prevOffset < $viewport && prevOffset < $startEffect) {
        if($useStartEffect) {
            marginTop = (prevOffset - $startEffect)*$ratio;
        } else {
            marginTop = (prevOffset - $viewport)*$ratio;       
        }
    }

    $footer.css({
        "margin-top": marginTop + 'px'
    });
}

$window.scroll(function () {
    footerParallax();
});

footerParallax();
```

Comment: almost, works fine in the small results area but buggy in a fullscreen mode http://jsfiddle.net/cnRsr/8/show/

Comment: For me this code shows the background dark-red which I believe should not be visible at any point.

Comment: @funkwurm: Yes - I mentioned that above as a break from the requirements.

Comment: @JFK Linked is a screenshot of the bottom portion of the screen on a high res monitor fullscreen. Where would you expect footer to appear in [this screen shot](http://i.imgur.com/WY2pJ5o.png)?

Comment: @dc5 : I will edit the question and add some graphics to make it clearer. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @dc5 : unfortunately it doesn't. I explained that in my question (What have I tried?) because the contents of the footer are messed up by the contents of the preceding section(s)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36596/discussion-between-dc5-and-jfk)

Comment: @dc5 : thanks for the fresh eyes, see my answer for the full and simpler code. PS. don't worry, the bounty will be granted automatically ;)

Answer (score 1):

This does what I think you need, the footer sticks when it has scrolled in view entirely:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/funkwurm/cnRsr/12/)

Code added:

```
function footerParallax() {
    var $scrollPos = $window.scrollTop() - $startEffect,
        $ratio = 0.6,
        $newTop = -($scrollPos * $ratio),
        $oldTop = parseInt($footer.css('top')),
        $nonRelTop = $footer.offset().top - $oldTop,
        $wanted = ($window.scrollTop()+$viewport-$footer.height());
    if ($nonRelTop + $newTop < $wanted) {
        $('#sectionC').css('display', 'none');
        $wanted = ($window.scrollTop()+$viewport-$footer.height());
        $nonRelTop = $footer.offset().top - $oldTop;
        $newTop = $wanted - $nonRelTop;
    } else {
        $('#sectionC').css('display', 'block');
    }    
    $footer.css('top', $newTop);
}

$window.scroll(footerParallax);
```

And in the CSS I added this so that `$footer.css('top')` wouldn't produce `NaN`:

```
#footer {
    top:0;
    /* ... */
}
```

***EDIT:*** A completely new approach after more clarification of OP. I now have a fixed position footer that starts increasing in height to take over the entire screen when the user has scrolled passed half of the document. The HTML, CSS and Javascript have all been updated to achieve this:

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/funkwurm/A7usT/1/)**

Comment: almost, works fine in the small results area but buggy in a fullscreen mode http://jsfiddle.net/funkwurm/cnRsr/10/show/

Comment: Works full screen for me in Chrome on Mac. What's buggy about it for you?

Comment: In fullscreen, when you reach the bottom of the page, the footer indeed stops scrolling but the rest of the page don't so the preceding `div` (#sectionC) shows up if footer's height is smaller than the fullscreen viewport (Firefox and Chrome in Windows)

Comment: So it should be that as you scroll down, you see `sectionC` briefly, but it gets overtaken by the `Footer` and won't be revealed after that? That was not clear to me from your initial post. Updated here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/funkwurm/cnRsr/12/)

Comment: I guess I need to clarify that in the question. It's not only sectionC that has to be covered, it should be any preceding element because you are actually sliding up the footer and covering/hiding what is above it while scrolling.

Comment: @JFK I added a new version that deviates from your original code more radically at the bottom, is this the effect you had in mind?

Comment: In your Fig C, you could scroll down still and see section C, which is what my first answer does (still available _[here](http://jsfiddle.net/funkwurm/cnRsr/10/)_. I don't see how what you want is different from what I originally had.